# Is there a reason why i am getting the error 500 Internal Server Error http://127.0.0.1:8000/sendEmail when i try to submit a form with Laravel

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-500

I have a contact form in which when the  user submits an email is send to the admin of the site and a copy to the user. However when i try to submit i get an error:

> Error: 500 Internal Server Error http://127.0.0.1:8000/sendEmail

On my Laravel debugger i get :

> View [view.name] not found. Users/user/Documents/Laravel
> Apps/GitHub/scinov_africa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php#137 InvalidArgumentException

I haven't been able to establish which view is missing and the reason i get the server error.

my Routes in web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\events\EventsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use App\Http\Controllers\project\ProjectsController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });

Route::get('/events', [EventsController::class, 'activities'])->name('events.activities');

Route::get('/coding-education', [ProjectsController::class, 'codingEducation'])->name('projects.codingEducation');
Route::get('/donate', [ProjectsController::class, 'donate'])->name('projects.donate');
Route::get('/donations', [ProjectsController::class, 'donations'])->name('projects.donations');
Route::get('/digital-exchange', [ProjectsController::class, 'digitalExchange'])->name('projects.digitalExchange');
Route::get('/contact-us', [ProjectsController::class, 'contactUs'])->name('projects.contact-us');
Route::post('/sendEmail', [ProjectsController::class, 'sendEmail'])->name('projects.sendEmail');

Route::get('/dashboard', function () { return view('dashboard'); })->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

my form

```
<form action="{{ route('projects.sendEmail') }}" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">

    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name"
                placeholder="Your Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
                placeholder="Your Email" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"
            required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="my-3">
        <div class="loading">Loading</div>
        <div class="error-message"> Message not sent</div>
        <div class="sent-message">Message sent successfully!</div>
        
        @if (session('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{ session('success') }}
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    
    <div class="text-center">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Send Message</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

my Logs read:

> local.ERROR: View [view.name] not found. {"exception":"[object]
> (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): View [view.name] not found. at
> /Users/user/Documents/Laravel
> Apps/GitHub/scinov_africa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137)

please help. I am in development mode and haven't deployed my code at all. I have just put my code in a folder named GitHub and it is therefore not a cloned app from GitHub.

I first thought the validate.js file was throwing the error because there is an issue with my form.. I haven't been able to approve of that.

```
// Function to submit the form data via AJAX
function php_email_form_submit(thisForm, action, formData) {
  // Send a POST request to the specified action URL with the form data
  fetch(action, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'} // Set the request header
  })
  .then(response => {
    // Check if the response status is OK (200)
    if (response.ok) {
      // If OK, return the response text (which may contain success or error information)
      return response.text();
    } else {
      // If not OK, throw an error with status, status text, and request URL information
      throw new Error(`${response.status} ${response.statusText} ${response.url}`);
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
    // After a successful response, remove the loading indicator
    thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');

    // Check the response data for success ('OK') or an error message
    if (data.trim() == 'OK') {
      // If success, display the success message and reset the form
      thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.add('d-block');
      thisForm.reset();
    } else {
      // If an error occurred, throw an error with the received error message
      throw new Error(data ? data : 'Form submission failed and no error message returned from: ' + action);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Catch and handle any errors that occurred during the request
    displayError(thisForm, error);
  });
}
```

i also checked in the functions rendering the views

```
public function contactUs()
    {


        return view('contact_us');
    }

    public function sendEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'required|string',
            'message' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        // Send an email to the admin
        Mail::to('opemba.m@taiwanafricaservice.org')->send(new  AdminEmail($validatedData));

        // Send a response email to the user
        Mail::to($validatedData['email'])->send(new  UserResponseEmail($validatedData));

        // Redirect back with a success message
        return back()->with('success', 'Your message has been sent successfully.');
    }
```

I am on Mac using Laravel 10.22 PHP 8.28

Comment: To: `return view('contact_us');` ... there is no route with a `contact_us` name that has an underscore `_`, but there _is_ a route to `contact-us` with the name `projects.contact-us`, if this is what might be needed instead?

Comment: your error is either in `AdminEmail` or in `UserResponseEmail`, but you didn't provide either of them

Comment: Looks like the problem is somewhere else. I have done that already.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found the error in the **AdminEmail**.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified what was wrong on my code. AdminResponse Class was not rightfully configured. In the content method the returned view was labled as view.name. See the code

```
 /**
 * Get the message content definition.
 */
public function content(): Content
{
    return new Content(
        view: 'view.name',
    );
}
```

I have updated the view returned with a view in my blade files. Now i am good.